# PowerApps SP Form - Referencing List item value in another List

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, people-picker, powerapps-forms

I have a strange situation, and I was hoping for some advice.  Basically, I have a PowerApps List Form (Customized SP form in PowerApps) that contains several fields, including a Lookup field to another list (List B), and a People field (Project Director).  List B has 60 rows with the following fields: Project (text field), and Project Director (people field).  The Lookup field in the first list (List A) displays all the Projects the user can select from (60 different projects from the 2nd list).  In list A, I need to auto populate it's own Project Director People field based on the selected project from the lookup.

Image of List B: [image]

So List A has the Lookup column which displays all 60 projects from the Project column in List B - this is the first row of List B.  So basically, I need the lookup column in List A to auto populate the Project Director People field in List A.  If I select "Test-Travel Personnel" in the List A Lookup field (in the PowerApp), I need List A's Project Director People field to auto populate with List B's associated Project Director.

I hope that made sense.

List A:
Project (Lookup)
Project Director (People)

List B (60 rows):
Project (Text field)
Project Director (People)

In the App: Select Project from Project Lookup field.  Project Director field should auto populate with List B's Project Director.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test  for your reference:

Here is listB

[image]

Here is list A

[image]

Here is newform:

```
DefaultSelectedItems: LookUp('List B',Project in DataCardValue2.Selected.Value).'Project Director'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  This resolved my issue perfectly.